# Conditional Trigonometric Identities on $A+B+C=π$.

Tags: trigonometry

If $A+B+C=\pi$ then prove that:
$$\tan A\tan B+\tan B\tan C+\tan C \tan A=1+\sec A\sec B\sec C$$

My Approach:

Given, $$A+B+C=\pi$$
$$A+B=\pi-C$$
$$\sin(A+B)=\sin(\pi-C)=\sin C$$
$$\cos(A+B)=\cos(\pi-C)=-\cos C$$

Now,

$$\text{L.H.S.}=\tan A \tan B+\tan B\tan C+\tan C\tan A$$
$$=\frac {\sin A\sin B}{\cos A\cos B}+\frac {\sin B\sin C}{\cos B\cos C} + \frac {\sin C\sin A}{\cos C\cos A}$$

I got struck at here. Please help me to move on.

Comment: You might try putting $\pi-A-B$ in place of $C$. $\qquad$

Comment: Note proper MathJax usage, as in my edits.  You had $A$+$B$+$C$=$\pi$ and I changed it to $A+B+C=\pi$, and I did changes more extensive than that in the later parts. $\qquad$